# htaccess redirection dynamic

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect /en/news/12345 to http://www.xyz.com/en/newsletters/12345

the only thing is that "en" and "12345" can change but "news" is always the same.

I have the following so far:

RewriteRule /^(.*)/news/(.*)$ http://www.xyz.com/$1/news/$2 [R=301,L]

but if i go to mydomain/wp-admin then i get an endless redirect?? Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem in your .htaccess file. Initially you had two conditions that prevented `RewriteRule . /swissfil3/index.php [L]` (catch-all) from redirecting when the path pointed to an existing file or folder (ignore-on-file):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

RewriteCond only applies to the rule directly followed by the condition.

When you added a new rule directly below these directives, the catch-all rule was not prevented from redirecting existing files or directories like /wp-admin. I.e. every request not matching any rules before catch-all would be redirected to /swissfin/3/index.php.

In additoin you used `(.)` to capture each part of the path. This would match one arbitrary character, but no more, so your redirect would be limited to /X/news/Y, instead of /XX/news/YYYY..., to fix this you can use `(.+)` which will match zero or more chars, or even better `([^/]*)` which will match zero or more characters not equal to /.

You should be able to avoid these problems by using the following code (where the catch-all directive has been moved directly below ignore-on-file, and the rewrite rule matches zero or more chars not equal to /):

```
# ...
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/news/([^/]*)$ http://www.xyz.com/$1/news/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /swissfin3/index.php [L]
```

Here you match every URL that contains a char

Comment: My mistake, try `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/news/([^/]*)$ http://www.xyz.com/$1/news/$2 [R=301,L]`, (.*) captured everything, including the slashes.. therfore `[^/]` = everyting except /.

Answer (score 0):

Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^en/news/([0-9]) http://www.xyz.com/en/newsletters/$1 [NC]

Please try this, hope it will solve your problem

Comment: @stianlik your rule is failing,mine is:
but it fails on /wpadmin

<pre>RewriteRule ^(.*)/news/(.*)$ http://www.swissfin.co.za/$1/news/$2 [R=301,L]</pre>

And my Htaccess looks like this:
<pre># BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /swissfin3/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/news/(.*)$ http://www.swissfin.co.za/$1/news/$2 [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^/(.*)/news/(.*)$ http://www.xyz.com/$1/news/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule . /swissfin3/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress</pre>

Comment: your rule
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/news/(.*)$ http://www.xyz.com/$1/news/$2 [R=301,L] fails